# What's the difference between "natural wealth" and "artificial poverty" in this qutoes?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Contentment is **natural wealth**; luxury is **artificial poverty**.

—By Socrates

I guess **natural wealth** means- a valuable possession exist in nature.
**artificial poverty** means -poor condition.

Comment: In other words, "he who is not contented with what he has, would not be contented with what he would like to have".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not Socrates (He wrote nothing down, and it doesn't appear in Plato's works, even when Plato claims to be quoting Socrates.

Many of these epigrams set up a paradox.  There's no special English meaning,  Artifical relates to things made by humans, Natural to things not made by humans.  Poverty is the opposite of wealth.  The epigram writer has set up opposites to challenge you to question what contentment really is. The philosophical point of view is called cynicism.

If you don't understand this, it is just because it is mysterious. There's no special understanding of the English words.

Comment: The source is from the 18th century https://books.google.de/books?id=K1cdAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA655&dq=socrates&hl=en#v=onepage&q=socrates&f=false